# How to Put Different Anchor on "data-url" Attribute in Just One Tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to modify this circle navigation: https://codepen.io/gzuzkstro/pen/oemMyN

In line 320, there's "rect" tag to generate all of the "Learn-more" buttons.
And in the javascript file line 160, there's "class_index" variable that indexing the navigations.

html file line 320:

```
<rect data-url="/industries" id="learn-more" x="280" y="250" width="90" height="30" />
```

js file line 160:

```
//There's a "serv-*" class for each bubble
let current_class = current.attr("class").split(" ")[1];
```

---

How do I use the index for the purpose of giving different anchor on "data-url" attribute?
The concept of my goal is like this, But I used multiple "button" tags.

```css
var learnMore = $('.learnmore');

$('.buttons').on('click', '.topic', function (event) {
  var url = $(event.target).data('url');
  learnMore.attr('href', url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="learnmore" href="#foo">Learn more</a>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="topic" data-url="#foo">Foo</button>
  <button class="topic" data-url="#bar">Bar</button>
  <button class="topic" data-url="#baz">Baz</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So, if I go to `Project Management`. What is the value of `data-url` in `Learn More` button?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the data-url attribute of the `learn more` element to change when you click on a given button?

Comment: Yes, you're correct @C.RaysOfTheSun

Comment: the value supposed to be anchor for each of the navigation @choz

Comment: @RendyEzaPutra Here's the [working pen](https://codepen.io/choz/pen/bmoybJ) - `Learn more` button should update its `data-url` based on `services_data.icon` thats provided.

Comment: I've tried your source, there's still no anchor on each of the "learn more" button. @choz

Comment: I already figured out a way to solve this. Thank you both for the idea, it helps me to think after a whole day trying to figure this out. hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  // our learn more element
  let $learnMore = $('.learnmore')

  $("button[class^='service serv-']").on('click', (e)=>{
    $($learnMore).attr('data-url', $(e.target).attr('data-url'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="learnmore" href="#foo">Learn more</a>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="service serv-1" data-url="#foo">Foo</button>
  <button class="service serv-2" data-url="#bar">Bar</button>
  <button class="service serv-3" data-url="#baz">Baz</button>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/JmrVwW) :)

#### Edit:

On the other hand, for your particular case, you could see [this one](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/LgzoOm) instead.

```
let learnMore = $('#learn-more');
// get the circle inside the group container
$("g[class^='service serv-'] circle").on('click', function(e){    
  // grab the value of the 'xlink:href' element inside the group container
  let dataUrl = $(this).parent().find('use').attr('xlink:href');
  // set the value above as the value of our #learn-more element's data-url attribute
  $(learnMore).attr('data-url', dataUrl);
  console.log($(learnMore).attr('data-url'))
});
```

(The code above is found in the end of script)

To be honest, I'm not entirely familiar with the elements you are currently working with. But, what I did was I grabbed a specific attribute from the `<use>` element inside the group container and set it as the value of the `data-url` attribute of the `#learn-more` rect.

On the other hand, in the working example above, I've also left some old code that set the class of the group container (`<g>` which seems to have the indexes you mentioned) as the value of the `data-url` attribute of the `#learn-more` rect instead

In case this does not satisfy your requirement, I hope you can take some ideas from it :)

Comment: How to implement this method to the 'circle-navigation' source code?